# Windows 8 or iOS App for Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, ios, windows-8, stack-overflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do Stack Overflow and other Stack Exchange sites have an app I can use?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/154797/do-stack-overflow-and-other-stack-exchange-sites-have-an-app-i-can-use)

Is there a Windows 8 or iOS app for Stack Overflow? I've been looking for an application for StackOverflow and I haven't been able to find anything via the App stores so I was wondering if there was an app somewhere out there hidden?

Comment: How did you not find anything in the App Store, if you search Stack Overflow the first 4 results are Stack Overflow apps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The mobile version of the website isn't bad, but if you're looking for native apps there are a few iOS ones (search "stack overflow" and you'll get some results) but they only allow you to browse questions as far as I can tell.

Comment: This is correct, unfortunately the SE API is read only :(

Comment: 2.1 might allow for write access, [currently in test for comments](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/write), @NSPostWhenIdle.

Comment: @Arjan That's awesome! Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0):

I developed a Windows 8 app for Stackoverflow [here](https://stackapps.com/questions/3717/stackstabilizer-a-windows-8-metro-app-version-2-11-05-2012) called [Stackstabilizer](https://stackapps.com/questions/3717/stackstabilizer-a-windows-8-metro-app-version-2-11-05-2012). It's updated often and should suit the average users needs.